# VB 2013 Creating 100 ovalshapes using a loop to simulate a complex network

Tags: vb.net, loops, draw, shapes

I am trying to simulate a complex network. I would like to represent 100 network nodes using OvalShape. (I plan to later connect these with lines according to a network connection alogirthm) I have the code below that creates 5 nodes just fine. However, I need to make 100 nodes. Can I somehow put this in a loop to create new OvalShapes and name them theNode1, theNode2, theNode3,... theNode100?

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim canvas As New ShapeContainer
    ' Set the form as the parent of the ShapeContainer.
    canvas.Parent = Me
    Dim theNode1 As New OvalShape
    Dim theNode2 As New OvalShape
    Dim theNode3 As New OvalShape
    Dim theNode4 As New OvalShape
    Dim theNode5 As New OvalShape


   ' Set the ShapeContainer as the parent of the OvalShape.
    theNode1.Parent = canvas
    theNode2.Parent = canvas
    theNode3.Parent = canvas
    theNode4.Parent = canvas
    theNode5.Parent = canvas

    theNode1.SetBounds(100, 100, 50, 50)
    theNode2.SetBounds(100, 200, 50, 50)
    theNode3.SetBounds(100, 100, 50, 50)
    theNode4.SetBounds(200, 200, 50, 50)
    theNode5.SetBounds(200, 100, 50, 50)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a separate variable for each node, you can have a [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of them:

```
Private Sub CreateOvals()
    Dim canvas As New ShapeContainer
    ' Set the form as the parent of the ShapeContainer.
    canvas.parent = Me
    Dim nodes As New List(Of OvalShape)

    ' create 5 nodes and set the .parent for each one
    For i = 0 To 4
        nodes.Add(New OvalShape With {.parent = canvas})
    Next

    ' call SetBounds as required
    nodes(0).SetBounds(100, 100, 50, 50)
    nodes(1).SetBounds(100, 200, 50, 50)
    nodes(2).SetBounds(100, 100, 50, 50)
    nodes(3).SetBounds(200, 200, 50, 50)
    nodes(4).SetBounds(200, 100, 50, 50)

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CreateOvals()

End Sub
```

It is usually better to call separate Subs from the Form1_Load handler - it makes it easier to modify a particular part without geting bogged down trying to figure out which section does what, and using meaningful names for methods makes it more readable.

Also, in case you haven't discovered it yet, I strongly recommend using [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) - and set it as the default in Visual Studio.